# p12 certificate is always incorrect at Pushwoosh

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, pushwoosh

I'm using Pushwoosh along with my Cordova App but I have now a problem to activate it. When I want to enable Pushwoosh for iOS I have to provide a 'Certificate File (.cer)' and a 'Push Certificate (.p12)'. Problem is that Pushwoosh **always** says that my .p12 file is incorrect (please have a look at the screenshot). I don't know why. I follow [this instructions](https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/ios/ios-configuration-guide/) in an exact manner! Do you think the documentation of Pushwoosh is broken?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now I works. It is **no where mentioned**, but in order to get the right .p12 file you have to unfold the private key certificate in your Keychain Access program, and then you must select both (the certificate and the key). Right click -> Export.